# Making a column row that is empty from database table not appear in my quiz?

Tags: php, html, forms, mysqli, radio-button

I'm trying to make it so that whenever there are empty cells in columns in my database table, they will not show up in my quiz application.

The way that the quiz is built up is that there are groups of four answers that share the same question ID (qid). When you press the next button you will get to see a set of four new questions and so on.

Right now there are empty spaces in quiz that are given a radiobutton on the side, How do I make it so that empty (answer) cells in my table column in mysql wont show up in my quiz?

**My SQL table columns:** `qid(int), answers(varchar), points(int)`

**My code (PHP/HTML)**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <script>
function goBack() {
    window.history.go(-1);
}
</script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php
    $localhost = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $connect = mysqli_connect($localhost, $username, $password) or die ("Kunde inte koppla");
    mysqli_select_db($connect, 'wildfire');

    $qid = 1; 
    if(count($_POST) > 0){ 
    $qid = intval($_POST['qid'])+1; 
    }
    ?>  
            <form method="post" action="">
                <input type="hidden" name="qid" value="<?=$qid?>">
                <?php
                    $sql1 = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT * FROM question where answer IS NOT NULL && qid =".intval($qid));
                    while($row1=mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql1)){
                    ?>
                    <input type='radio' name='answer1' value="<?php echo $row1['Point'];?>"><?php echo $row1['answer'];?><br>
                    <?php
                    }
                ?>
                    <button type="button" onclick="history.back();">Tillbaka</button>
                <input type='submit' name='forward' value='Nästa'>

            </form>
        </body>

    </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your SQL you have excluded results where the answer is NULL.

Is this how you are storing an empty answer field in your db table; as NULL?

If so you should not get any results for where the field 'answer' is set to NULL.

Maybe you are storing a string instead of NULL. You can use this code to see what is returned from an empty answer cell:

```
if($row['answer'] == '')
{
    echo "Answer is an empty string.";
}
else if(is_null($row['answer'])){
    echo "Answer is NULL value.";
}
else if($row['answer'] == "NULL")
{
    echo "Answer is the string 'NULL'.";
}
```

At least now, you will know what the empty answer field in your table are being stored as, and then you can go about removing them from your quiz.

You could also use your Database Management System (PHPMyAdmin) to check how data is being stored.

Hope this Helps

Comment: I want to make it so that empty rows from my database wont show up on my page, since I'm storing empty rows from a previous page onto my database. Is there a way to hide the rows, since right now they output an empty row with a radio button on the side.

Comment: As per my answer what are you storing empty values in your database as? Have you checked, by looking in your dB management or by using the code?

Comment: They are stored as ' ' (not NULL). All that the code you provided me with does is tell me that answer is an empty string. EDIT: I am storing empty strings, but not as NULL.

Comment: You are correct, that is what the code does. Now we know they are not null there is no point having not null in ur SQL, instead use != '' (is not equal to an empty string). alternatively set ur dB to include null in these fields for no content, then your original code should work.

Comment: I've tried it, although it works and hides everything on the sql table that is empty, it doesnt work on my form and is still shown on my application.

Comment: here is my sql query: SELECT qid,Point,answer,tid,aid FROM question
WHERE answer != '"';

Comment: That SQL is quite different than the SQL in your originally question. Have you modified the SQL stored in $sql1 to exclude answers with empty strings? If so it should be working.

Comment: Nevermind I made a small error in my query. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Glad I could help you, upvote answer or comment to reflect that it was useful to you, Cheers